# Applying LIMIT and OFFSET to MS SQL server 2008 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to apply `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to original query (without modifying it) in MSSQL server 2008.

Let's say the original query is:

```
SELECT * FROM energy_usage
```

(But it can be any arbitrary SELECT query)

That's what I came up with so far:

**1.** It does what I need, but the query generates **extra** column **row_number** which I don't need.

```
WITH OrderedTable AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row_number,  * FROM energy_usage
)   
SELECT * FROM OrderedTable WHERE row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

**2.** This one doesn't work for some reason and returns the following error.

```
SELECT real_sql.* FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row_number, * FROM (SELECT * FROM energy_usage) as real_sql) as subquery
WHERE row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

More common case is:

```
SELECT real_sql.* FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row_number,  * FROM (real sql query) as real_sql) as subquery
WHERE row_number BETWEEN {offset} + 1 AND {limit} + {offset}
```

**Error:**

> The column prefix 'real_sql' does not match with a table name or alias
>   name used in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not put it on `SELECT` list:

```
WITH OrderedTable AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row_number,  * 
 FROM energy_usage
)   
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM OrderedTable WHERE row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

`SELECT *` is common anti-pattern and should be avoided anyway. Plus `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` will not give you guarantee of stable sort between executions.

Second if you need only ten rows use:

```
 SELECT TOP 10 *
 FROM energy_usage
 ORDER BY ...
```

---

Unfortunately you won't get something nice as [Selecting all Columns Except One](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/05/14/selecting-all-columns-except-one-in-postgresql/)

```
WITH OrderedTable AS
    (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row_number,  * 
     FROM energy_usage
    )   
SELECT * EXCEPT row_number FROM OrderedTable WHERE row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately I can't use your first suggestion since the original query has to be unmodified (Original query is an arbitrary SELECT statement), also I need to pass Offset and Limit (1 and 10 is just an example). Updated the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

This would solve the problem.

```
DECLARE @offset INT = 1;
DECLARE @limit INT = 10;

WITH Filtered AS (
    SELECT TOP (@offset + @limit) *
    FROM energy_usage
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
), Results AS (
    SELECT TOP (@limit) *
    FROM Filtered
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM Results
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Comment: The offset won't work correctly if you ask for a range that's outside of the amount of available rows. For example a table with 10 rows and an offset of 50 (shouldn't return any row).

Comment: @Chamika       The solution will work correctly only if the ORDER BY 1 - has unique values. But since the original query is arbitrary, we can't rely on that.